# How to give automatic number when the user inputs name? Using Queue in C

Tags: c, queue

Student here.

My program needs to give a customer number starting from 1 when the user inputs a name. For example, if The user inputs "Althea" The program should give the customer number 1 to althea, when another name is inputted the program will give the customer number 2. I also need it if the other function is used, for example, if The user also did the dequeue function, the program should print, Customer number 1 "Althea" is deleted, same in peek operation "Customer number 1 'Althea' is first in line" and same in the display function, The program should display the customer number and the customer name. I do not know where to begin to do this. How to do this?

Comment: For the future, you are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide detailed information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your customers' numbers stored somewhere.

```
struct customer {
    char name[NAME_MAX];
    int  number;
};
```

Your queue can be implemented as a singly linked list:

```
struct list {
    struct customer customer;
    struct list *next;
};
```

with:

- `enqueue()` being a `push_back()` on your list.
- `dequeue()` being a `pop_front()` on your list.

And your queue data structure:

```
struct queue {
    struct list *front;
    struct list *rear;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};
```

From that, you can write your enqueuing and dequeuing logic:

```
int enqueue(struct queue *q, const char *name)
{
    if (!q) return 0;
    if (q->size == q->capacity) return -1;
    
    int number = q->rear ? q->rear->customer.number+1 : q->size;
    
    struct list *item = list_new(name, number);
    if (!item) return -2;
    
    
    if (q->rear == NULL) {
        q->front = item;
        q->rear = item;
    } else {
        q->rear->next = item;
        q->rear = q->rear->next;
    }
    
    ++q->size;
    return 1;
}
```

```
int dequeue(struct queue *q, struct list **first)
{
    if (!q) return 0;
    if (q->size == 0) return -1;
    
    struct list *item = q->front;
    
    if (q->front == q->rear) {
        q->front = NULL;
        q->rear = NULL;
    } else {
        q->front = q->front->next;
    }
    
    item->next = NULL;
    first ? *first = item : free(item);
    return 1;
}
```

`list_new()` is to create a new list node:

```
struct list *list_new(const char name[NAME_MAX], int number)
{
    struct list *item = malloc(sizeof *item);
    if (!item) return NULL;
    
    snprintf(item->customer.name, NAME_MAX, "%s", name);
    item->customer.number = number;
    item->next = NULL;
    return item;
}
```

If you need the peek:

```
int queue_peek(struct queue *q, struct customer *cust)
{
    if (!q) return 0;
    *cust = q->front->customer;
    return 1;
}
```

And to initialize your queue:

```
void queue_init(struct queue *q, const size_t capacity)
{
    q->front = NULL;
    q->rear  = NULL;
    q->size  = 0;
    q->capacity  = capacity;
}
```

Your code now should be straightforward.

---

Nice to read: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).